# Why does Framer Motion's page transitions cause my page to shift/adjust on every page transition?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I am using Next.js, Framer Motion, and Sanity. I added page transitions with AnimatePresence to _app.js with exitBeforeEnter and it works fine for the most part except for a small UI issue. Everytime I load a new page, the new page will adjust/shift into place, it happens very fast but I would like to eliminate this issue. I have a feeling it has to do with rendering the data from Sanity. Does anyone have any insight to this problem? I noticed when I went from UseEffect to getServerSideProps for data fetching, the problem resolved for that page (services). The only page that uses useEffect is the feeders page.

Here is my _app.js

```html
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <Layout>
      <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
        <motion.div
          key={router.route}
          initial="hidden"
          animate="enter"
          exit="exit"
          variants={{
            hidden: {
              opacity: 0,
              x: -200,
              y: 0,
            },
            enter: {
              opacity: 1,
              x: 0,
              y: 0,
            },
            exit: {
              opacity: 0,
            },
          }}
        >
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </motion.div>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Website: [BOM Reptiles](https://bomreptiles.com)

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined  a `exitBeforeEnter` property to the `AnimatePresence` component?

Comment: I did, I added the code snippet. Everything works fine except for a small adjustment that happens when loading the page. The transitions exit then enters like its supposed to.

Comment: Asking a question about the original question is better suited as a Comment. I suggest asking as a comment, then coming back and answering when the information is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried switching from useEffect to useLayoutEffect, no change. So I switched from useEffect to getServerSideProps for data fetching and added initial={false} to AnimatePresense and now I get no more UI shifting/adjusting on load.  I guess pre-rendering the data does the trick

Comment: That would be nice to add the working code snippet to your answer for someone who might need details :)